# Fortran Inquire gives UNDEFINED and UNKNOWN

Tags: fortran

I have created a text file using an editor and put some information in it

When calling inquire as follows I am getting UNDEFINED and UNKNOWN

```
Inquire (file=nm, exist=fe, form=fm, access=ac)
Inquire (file=nm, sequential=seq, direct=drc)
Inquire (file=nm, formatted=fmt, unformatted=uft)
```

Outputs

```
fm, ac: UNDEFINED UNDEFINED
seq: UNKNOWN
drc: UNKNOWN
fmt: UNKNOWN
uft: UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Are those files which have been connected somehow?

Comment: What you mean by connected? I just created a file with emacs.

Comment: Have you `open`ed them?

Comment: I have not opened them with a fortran call to open. I just have a file and wish to see what type of file it is and whether it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's appealing to think that so-called *inquire by file* tells us what we can do with a file.  Indeed, using the `file=` specifier in the `inquire` statement inquires about a file which needn't exist or be connected (through, say, an `open` statement).  It seems that you're finding existence testing not to be troubling.

However, the information we get from such an inquiry is limited.  Yes, it would be nice if an inquire by file like

```
inquire(file="some_file", direct=isdirect, formatted=isformatted, ...)
```

tells us whether it is possible to establish a direct access connection to a file which has unformatted records, but we're in the realms of "processor dependent".

First, though, the easy ones in the question: `form=` and `access=` specifiers.  You are seeing `undefined`, which is precisely the result that is expected when the files are not currently connected.  You can see in Fortran 2008 9.2.10.3 for `access=`

> If there is no connection, it is assigned the value UNDEFINED.

and similarly in `9.2.10.12` for `form=`.  Even with inquire by file, these two specifiers tell us about the *connection* not the file.  That is, not what *may* we do with the file, but what *are* we doing with the file.

The others, which have `unknown` are covered by statements such as

> UNKNOWN if the processor is unable to determine whether SEQUENTIAL is
>   included in the set of allowed access methods for the file

(for `sequential=`).  Knowing whether an access mode, say, is allowed is more expected for things like

> For example, a processor may allow only sequential access to a file on magnetic tape. Thus, the set of
>   allowed access methods depends on the file and the processor.